# In which environment should I store package data the user (and functions) should be able to modify?

Tags: r, namespaces, package

### background

I am the maintainer of two packages that I would like to add to CRAN. They were rejected because some functions assign variables to `.GlobalEnv`. Now I am trying to find a different but as convenient way to handle these variables.

### the packages

Both packages belong to the [*Database of Odorant Responses*, DoOR](http://neuro.uni-konstanz.de/DoOR/2.0/). We collect published odor-response data in the `DoOR.data` package, the algorithms in the `DoOR.functions` package merge these data into a single *consensus dataset*.

### intended functionality

The data package contains a precomputed *consensus dataset*. The user is able to modify the underlying original datasets (e.g. add his own datasets, remove some...) and compute a new *consensus dataset*. Thus the functions must be able to access the modified datasets.

The easiest way was to load the complete package data into the `.GlobalEnv` (*via* a function) and then modify data there. This was also straight forward for the user, as he saw the relevant datasets in his "main" environment. The problem is that writing into the user environment is bad practice and CRAN wouldn't accept the package this way (understandable).

### things I tried

1. assigning only modified datasets to `.GlobalEnv`, non explicitly *via* `parent.frame()` - [Hadley](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/656792542415982592) pointed out that this is still bad, in the end we are writing into the users environment.
2. writing only modified datasets into a dedicated new environment `door.env <- new.env()`.

   1. `door.env` is not in the search path, thus data in it is ignored by the functions
   2. putting it into the search path with `attach(door.env)`, as I learned, creates a new environment in the search path, thus any further edits in `new.env()` will again be ignored by the functions
   3. it is complicated to see and edit the data in `new.env` for the user, I'd rather have a solution where a user would not have to learn environment handling

So bottom line, with all solutions I tried I ended up with multiple copies of datasets in different environments and I am afraid that this confuses the average user of our packe (including me :))

Hopefully someone has an idea of where to store data, easily accessible to user and functions.

EDIT: the data is stored as `*.RData` files under /data in the `DoOR.data` package. I tried using `LazyData = true` to avoid loading all the data into the `.GlobalEnv`. This works good, the probllems with the manipulated/updated data remain.

Comment: I'm interested in other responses, but off the top of my head, perhaps put the data in an option, such as `options(concensus_data = [default_data])`.  Set the default using the `.onLoad` function, and then your functions can reference `concensus_data <- getOption("concensus_data")`?

Comment: @RichardScriven, I would have suggested that too, except that the data need to be easily accessible by his functions.  I interpreted that as meaning he wants a common location for the data without having to specify the data set in every function call. (and the need to modify the data rules out a `sysdata.rda`)

Comment: I think you basically just want to follow the advice in [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages). Put the data in `/data` in the data package and allow users to load it with `data("datafile")`. They can then pass that to whatever functions you're offering in the second package. If that's not sufficient, perhaps clarify the mechanism through which you're recomputing the "consensus dataset".

Comment: Maybe for further clarification: Loading the data works fine but both my functions and the user need to edit the data. i am trying to find the proper place to store the modified data so that the functions still find it.

Some functions update several datasets thus I cant't simply return the modified data but have to use `assign()`.

Comment: Maybe you can work on improving your approach #2. To get rid the problems 2.1 and 2.2 you can use functions to get and set the data, instead of accessing it directly (see eg http://www.r-bloggers.com/getters-and-setters-in-r/). To solve 2.3, you can create functions for the user to see/edit the data ,e.g. instead of the user  just typing `consensus` (assuming that's the name of the dataset) he will have to call a function `ViewData("consensus")` and inside `ViewData` you will use the getter function that you defined before.

Comment: @konvas approach sound promising. But what would be left is that if the user calls `consensus` he would call the version from `package:DoOR.data` without recognizing.
Personally I like that when I use `LazyData` and make assignments to `parent.frame()` from within functions, whenever a dataset is modified it appears in the `.GlobalEnv`. This way I have easy cotrol of what was modified and can return to the initial state by simply `rm()` datasets from `.GlobalEnv`. But I am not sure whether this is sufficient for CRAN.

Comment: Is it necessary for `consensus` to be in the global environment? If you only kept it in `door.env`, just typing `consensus` in the command line would throw a "object not found" error. The user would have to type `door.env$consensus` in which the updated/modified data would be returned (but they wouldn't do that; you would tell them to use your own function for viewing/editing which will be more user friendly)